# A specific user is unable to log in to vsftpd

Tags: 11.04, ftp, users, chroot, vsftpd

I am setting up a new user let his name be `ftpguy`. He has access to only one directory `/var/www/xxx`. I have already chowned the directory so that he has write and read privileges. The user is also unable to login via ssh as I have disabled that by changing his shell to `/sbin/nologin`.

Also, in vsftpd config, I have enabled the `chroot_local_user`. Now whenever I log in from ftp, i get an auth error.

```
Connect socket #1008 to xxxxxxxx, port 21...   
220 Welcome to blah FTP service.  
USER ftpguy  
331 Please specify the password.  
PASS **********  
530 Login incorrect.
```

I changed the password to something different several times, using the passwd command, nothing happens, i still the above error.

However I am able to log in with my ssh creditals to my ftp server without any problems.(I do not use a key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across this while letting my friend piggy back off my vps. I had to set his shell to a real shell instead or /bin/false or /bin/nologin. I then used the *DenyUsers* option in sshd_config to prevent him connecting via ssh.

It may be a bug with VsFTP but I didnt have time to get to the bottom of it yet.